# Check if value of parameter in each dict of a list is sequential

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to check if the current `id` equals last `id` +1, (this should work for any number of similar dicts added in the list)

#### Code

```sh
listing = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'stuff': "othervalues"
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'stuff': "othervalues"
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'stuff': "othervalues"
    }
]

for item in listing :
    if item[-1]['id'] == item['id']+1:
        print(True)
```

#### Output

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samuk\Desktop\Master\DV\t2\tester.py", line 10, in <module>
    if item[-1]['id'] == item['id']+1:
KeyError: -1
```

#### Desired result

```
True
```

**or, in case of fail,**

```
False
```

Comment: What is `item[-1]` meant to be doing?

Comment: `item` is `dict`, `item[-1]` would raise `KeyError` if `-1` doesn't exist.

Comment: at the place of `item[-1]` , should be the previous `item['id']` in the list

Comment: I just don't know how to get this previous `item['id']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if all the `id`s are in a sequence we can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) here.

```
def is_sequential(listing):
    start = listing[0]['id']
    for idx, item in enumerate(listing, start):
        if item['id'] != idx:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thank you, that will do!

Answer (score 2):

You can save the last id in a variable.

```
id = listing[0]['id']

for item in listing[1:]:
    if id == item['id']:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
    id = item['id']
```

Answer (score 1):

As the saying goes... "There are many ways to skin a cat". So here's another way:

```
listing = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'stuff': "othervalues"
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'stuff': "othervalues"
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'stuff': "othervalues"
    }
]
for i, v in enumerate(listing[1:], 1):
    print(v['id'] - 1 == listing[i-1]['id'])
```

Of course, rather than just checking like this you could always sort the list!

Comment: Sure there are a lot of ways in python :p coming to `rather than just checking like this you could always sort the list` in terms of complexity sorting would `O(NlogN)` and one more pass over the list to check equality, while posted solution would take `O(N)` but yes `sort` is implemented in `C` and might outperform `for`.

Comment: My point was that if the list is only valid when the IDs are in order then what's the point of checking to see if it's out of order? Chances are that the use-case requires that they are in order. But, of course, we don't actually know that

Answer (score 1):

When you do `for item in some_list`, `item` is *the actual item* in that list. You can't get the previous item by `item[-1]`.

So in your case, `item` is a dictionary that has the keys `'id'` and `'stuff'`. Obviously, no key called `-1`, so you get a `KeyError`.

You can iterate over two slices of the list after using `zip()` -- one that starts at the zeroth element, and one that starts on the first element. Using `zip()`, you can get corresponding items of these slices simultaneously. You'll have every item and its subsequent item coming out of `zip()`.

Also, you want a result *after* you've checked all pairs of items, not *while* you're checking each pair. To do this, create a variable `is_sequential` with an initial value of `True`. If you find a single pair that doesn't work, change this to `False`, and break out of the loop because one pair being non-sequential makes the entire list so.

```
is_sequential = True
for item1, item2 in zip(listing, listing[1:]):
    if item1['id'] + 1 != item2['id']:
        is_sequential = False
        break

print(is_sequential)
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function with the same loop and condition, and then invert the result, or use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) with the opposite condition:

```
# use any()
is_sequential = not any( item1['id'] + 1 != item2['id']
                     for item1, item2 in zip(listing, listing[1:])  
                    )

# or, use all()
is_sequential = all( item1['id'] + 1 == item2['id']
                     for item1, item2 in zip(listing, listing[1:])  
                    )
```

Comment: I'm sure you know this but instead of `not any(...)` you could use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and it's more pythonic imo

Comment: @Ch3steR you're right, early morning brainfart. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `sorted` and `range` to evaluate if the identifiers are sequential:

```py
from typing import Dict, List

def is_sequential(records: List[Dict], key: str) -> bool:
    values = [value[key] for value in records]
    return sorted(values) == list(range(min(values), max(values)+1))

print(is_sequential(listing, "id"))
```

Note: Solution is based on approach #1 in this [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-check-if-list-contains-consecutive-numbers/) and only works with integers.

---

However, I like Pranav Hosangadi's approach with a list comprehension better. But I would replace `not any()` with `all()` as suggested by Ch3steR in the comments:

```py
from typing import Dict, List

def is_sequential(records: List[Dict], key: str) -> bool:
    return all(l[key]+1 == r[key] for l, r in zip(records, records[1:]))

print(is_sequential(records, "id"))
```

---

*Ch3steR's solution is probably the most readable code.*

Comment: Nice one! You have by mistakenly marked `records: dict` it should be `records: list` or much better `List[Dict]`(from `typing` module).

Comment: Oops, yes, you are right. I updated the answer. Thank you!